# B & W balls in box. If any time we draw out a ball, the current count of white is always more than black, how many possible cases?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $m$ white balls, and $n$ black balls in box. $m > n$. We draw out balls one by one. When we finish, we have ${n+m} \choose n$ different sequences. Now I add one restriction: at any time we draw out a ball, the current count of white balls should always be more than black balls. Then with this restriction, how many possible cases we have?

Definitely we will have fewer cases than ${n+m} \choose n$, but I have no idea is there any way to figure the accurate answer out. Thank you!

Comment: We draw one by one so we have ${m+n\choose 1}$ possibilities how n is lower summand

Comment: I mean ${m+n} \choose n$ many different sequences

Comment: Please see [Bertrand's Ballot Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) An MSE search will also get some hits.

Comment: Gotta. Thanks a lot!